# How to implement a lookup table on a set of bit-field flags in C?

Tags: c

I have a set of flags using bitfields, based on user input these flags will be set and the program should respond accordingly and clear the corresponding request, my current implementation works and serves the intended purpose, however I do acknowledge that my current approach will not be scalable, I believe there has to be a better way of implementing this perhaps using a lookup table but I am unsure about how to do so. Any help or advise is highly appreciatted.

```
typedef union{

    volatile uint32_t all_flags;                                
    
    struct{
    
        volatile bool flag_a                            : 1;
        volatile bool flag_b                            : 1;
        volatile bool flag_c                            : 1;        
    
    }type;              

} flags_t; 

flags_t foo;

void flags_set_thread(uint8_t val){

   if(val == 0x12){
      foo.type.flag_a = true;
   } 
   else if(val == 0x34){
      foo.type.flag_b = true;
   }
   else if(val == 0x56){
      foo.type.flag_c = true; 
   }

}

int main(){
   
   while(1){

     if(foo.type.flag_a){
       printf("Perform corresponding task to flag a and clear flag \n");
       foo.type.flag_a = false;  
     }
     else if(foo.type.flag_b){
      printf("Perform corresponding task to flag b and clear flag \n");
      foo.type.flag_b = false; 
     }
     else if(foo.type.flag_c){
      printf("Perform corresponding task to flag c and clear flag \n");
      foo.type.flag_c = false;
     }

   }

   return 0;

}
```

The initial question would be essentially, How could I create a Lookup table to which I could assign and index to every flag so that no **ifelse is required**.

Cheers,

Comment: That could be accomplished by just bitshifting the argument by `n` to get/set/compare the `n`th flag.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use bitfields for it. Let the compiler create the lookup tables for you. Macro definitions are good if you assign compile const values as it will not generate any branches.

```
#define flag_a     (1U << 0)
#define flag_b     (1U << 1)
#define flag_c     (1U << 2)

#define SET_F(var, flag, val) ((val) ? ((var) |= (flag)) : ((var) &= (~(flag))))

volatile uint32_t flags;

void flags_set_thread(uint32_t val)
{

    switch(val)
    {
        case 0x12:
         SET_F(flags, flag_a, 1);
         break;
        case 0x34:
         SET_F(flags, flag_b, 1);
         break;
        case 56:
         SET_F(flags, flag_c, 1);
         break;
    }
}

int main(){
   
    while(1){
        switch(flags)
        {
            case flag_a:
             /* do something*/
             SET_F(flags, flag_a, 0);
             break;
            case flag_b:
             /* do something*/
             SET_F(flags, flag_b, 0);
             break;
            case flag_c:
             /* do something*/
             SET_F(flags, flag_c, 0);
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dvfo3a6oa